# Use PHP and LDAP to list all Active Directory groups?

Tags: php, ldap

I want to list all the groups, regardless of the current user, on a PHP page. I can find info on how to list all the groups a user is a member of, but not just list EVERY group.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to query for (objectClass=Group) and list the results.

Answer (score 0):

Very old post but no reasonable answer yet. If anyone whose looking for a solution (like myself) you can try:

```
$basedn = "OU=Managed,OU=Groups,DC=YOUR,DC=ORGANIZATION,DC=DETAILS,DC=com";
$sr = ldap_list($YOUR_LDAP_CONN, $basedn, "cn=*", array('cn'));
$info = ldap_get_entries($ldapconn, $sr);
```

If your not sure of your `$basedn` or the above `$basedn` doesn't work for you. You can use [Active Directory Explorer GUI](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963907.aspx://)  to find your `$basedn`